# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable exception in HBase

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

We tried to test the following example code for accessing HBase tables (Spark-1.3.1, HBase-1.1.1, Hadoop-2.7.0):

```
import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print >> sys.stderr, """
        Usage: hbase_inputformat <host> <table>
        Run with example jar:
        ./bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /path/to/example/jar \
        /path/to/examples/hbase_inputformat.py <host> <table>
        Assumes you have some data in HBase already, running on <host>, in <table>
        """
        exit(-1)

    host = sys.argv[1]
    table = sys.argv[2]
    sc = SparkContext(appName="HBaseInputFormat")

    conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host, "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": table}
    keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"
    valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"

    hbase_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",
        keyConverter=keyConv,
        valueConverter=valueConv,
        conf=conf)
    output = hbase_rdd.collect()
    for (k, v) in output:
        print (k, v)

    sc.stop()
```

We got the following error:

> 15/10/14 12:46:24 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/opt/python/son.py", line 30, in 
>           conf=conf)
>         File "/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 547, in newAPIHadoopRDD
>           jconf, batchSize)
>         File "/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in **call**
>         File "/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
>       py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
>       : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>               at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
>               at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:157)
>               at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDDFromClassNames(PythonRDD.scala:509)
>               at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala:494)
>               at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>               at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
>               at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
>               at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
>               at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>               at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>               at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Any insights are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you haven't got the HBase libs in your classpath. You will need hbase-common and hbase-client jars, which you should pass to pyspark via the --jars  parameters

Comment: Thanks Erik Schmiegelow. But i get another error as per below

api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(R                                                                                        pcRetryingCaller.java:208)

Please give me some advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by execute the MapReduce Job by adding hbase-common.jar in environment variable: HADOOP_CLASSPATH:

```
 export
 HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HBASE_HOME/lib/hbase-common-1.3.1.jar
```